# How to group data by more than one column with groupby - if possible

Tags: python, pandas

Using `groupby` with `pandas`, I can get a count and percentage from a spreadsheet that will tell me the racial breakdown of our school by "Grade" OR the "Livewith" (Single Parent) breakdown.

```
df.groupby('GradeEntering)['Race'].value_counts(normalize = False).
```

What I can't find out how to do is get it broken down by "GradeEntering" AND "RACE" AND "Liveswith"

I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of rows like below:

| GradeEntering | Race | Liveswith |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kindergarten | W | Both Parents |
| Kindergarten | B | Mother |
| Kindergarten | W | Father |
| First | W | Both Parents |
| Kindergarten | W | Both Parents |
| Kindergarten | B | Mother |
| Kindergarten | W | Father |
| First | W | Both Parents |

Desired output would be Number of "Kindergarten" who are "W" and live with "Both Parents", then "Kindergarten" who are "W" and live with "Mother", and so on.  So I have both counts and percentages.  This is important to us as we try to represent our community population within our small charter school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list:

```
(df.groupby(['GradeEntering', 'Race', 'Liveswith'])['Race']
   .value_counts(normalize=False)
 )
```